# uWSGI --reload breaks logrotate

Tags: django, wsgi, uwsgi, django-wsgi

I start uWSGI with the command:

```
uwsgi --socket=127.0.0.1:8080--daemonize=uwsgi.out --module=web.wsgi:application --env
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=web.settings --env --master --pidfile=uwsgi.pid --processes=10
--harakiri=120 --max-requests=5000 --vacuum
--log-maxsize=1000000 --propagate-touch --touchlogrotate=uwsgi.logrotate
```

Everything works as expected and logs are rotated both when the `log-maxsize` limit is reached as well as when I touch the file specified by `touchlogrotate`. But once I reload uWSGI (by appending `--reload ./uwsgi.pid` to the above) both `--log-maxsize` and `--touchlogrotate` cease to work. The only solution I've found is a hard restart.